# Checking the positive semi-definiteness of the square of a matrix

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, matrix-norms

I'm reading a paper [1], which provides a condition for checking whether the square of a matrix is positive semi-definite: suppose that $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a real-valued square matrix, then the symmetric part of $A^2 = A A$ is positive semi-definite as long as $A$ is positive semi-definite and
$$
\|A - A^{T} \|_2 \leq \|A + A^{T} \|_2.
$$

This proposition is given in a remark without proof. Appreciate it if anyone can help to prove.

[1] On the Convergence of Projection Methods:
Application to the Decomposition of
Affine Variational Inequalities

Comment: For some matrix $B$, what does $\big \Vert B\big \Vert_2$ mean?  The most common interpretation is the operator 2 norm of the matrix but this is obviously not true, e.g. consider applying your criterion to $A := \left[\begin{matrix} 10 & 0& 0\\0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: Denote the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts of $A$ by $H$ and $K$ respectively. What the authors assert is that $H^2+K^2$ is PSD whenever $\|H\|_2\ge\|K\|_2$. As shown by user8675309's comment above, this is clearly false. A correct sufficient condition is that $H$ is nonsingular and $\|KH^{-1}\|_2\le1$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, I think it is a valid counterexample. Indeed, the original also impose the condition that $A$ itself is also positive semi-definite, but this this counterexample is still valid. We may conclude that the remark in the paper is not correct.